# group pandas time-series data frame using specific time intervals

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large csv file with time stamp data in the iso format `2015-04-01 10:26:41`. The data span multiple months with entries ranging from 30 secs apart to multiple hours. It's columns are id, time, speed.

Ultimately I want to group data by a time interval of 15 mins, then calculate an average speed, for however many entries are in the 15 mins timeslot.

I am trying to use Pandas because it seems like it has a solid time-series tools and it might be easy to do this, but I am falling at the first hurdle.

So far I have imported the CSV as a dataframe and, all columns have a dtype of `object`. I have sorted the data by date and am now trying to group the entries by a time interval which is where i'm struggling. Based around google searching, I have tried to `resample` the data using this code `df.resample('5min', how=sum)` Here I get the error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex`. I was thinking about trying the `groupby`method, perhaps using `lambda` as in `df.groupby(lambda x:x.minutes + 5)` which produces the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'minutes'`.

Basically I'm a little confused as to a) whether pandas has the time-series data in a format it's recognising as it's `dtype` is `object`, and b) if it can recognize it I can't seem to get the time-intervals down.

Keen to learn if anyone could point me in the right direction.

DF looks like this

```
        0        1                    2      3       
0          id  boat_id                 time  speed     
1      386226       32  2015-01-15 05:14:32      4.2343243      
2      386285       32  2015-01-15 05:44:57      3.45234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it looks like you read a blank row.  You probably want to skip the first row in your file `pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1)`.

You should convert the text representation of the time into a DatetimeIndex using `pd.to_datetime()`.

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['time']), inplace=True)
```

You should then be able to resample.

```
df.resample('15min', how=np.mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's answer is correct; also note that you can do

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=True)
```

And your date column should have the datetime type if the format is sane. Then you can set the index and resample as above.